# WPF DataGrid with multipleLines rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid, multiline

I have the next 2 grids and the same header structure:
[grids structure](http://img.ly/8wwB)

The most importent thing from this structure is to implement the double line functionality on the header and also on the grids.
I need to have the sorting functionality on the first line and also on the second, and to have the default header style on bought lines( because if I add 2 textblocks in one header they will not have this functionality).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This might be part of you answer

```
    <TextBlock>LineOne<LineBreak/>LineTwo</TextBlock>
```